# Custom Wordpress Theme - Menu has multiple fonts on one element only in Chrome?

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, menu, fonts

In the process of designing a Wordpress site, usually don't have a problem, but this one is bugging me!

See screenshot below, the 'A' element of the 'LI' element has multiple fonts, seen only in Chrome.
IE, Safari and Firefox render fine.

[image: Wordpress Menu Chrome Font Issue]

Temp site is; http://www.diamag.net/bes/

Any idea's?

Cheers,
Ollie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use chrome 19 on debian 6, this is my screenshot (looks fine to me, but i need glasses)

[image]

maybe explain the ellipses

Comment: That's what it was! No idea why though, if I use Chrome Developer Tools and remove the ellipse then it displays fine! Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I use chrome 29 on windows, the font displays just fine. Try opening your browser in Incognito Mode and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Likewise. Although, as @gwillie has pointed out, it was the ellipse's - no idea why though!! Thanks anyway.